# Counting characters from a user inputted string of more than one word

Tags: java, string, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a program where the user inputs a word and then the program displays every letter of the alphabet with a number next to it that shows how many times that letter was used in the word. It works great, but the only problem is that it only works with one word strings. How can I add detection for strings of more than one word? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterOccurrenceCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int array[] = new int[26]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        { 
        array[i] = 0; 
        } 

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String userInput; 
        System.out.println("Please enter a string."); 
        userInput = Keyboard.next().toLowerCase(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) 
        { 
            char ch = userInput.charAt(i); 
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { 
            array[ch - 'a'] ++; 
            } 
        }

        for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ++ch) { 
            System.out.print(ch + " = " + array[ch-'a'] + " | ");
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Change `Keyboard.next()` to `Keyboard.nextLine()`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!